# How to access custom settings in an extension method for IApplicationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I am writing extension methods extension methods for my service to add it to the IServiceCollection and use it at the IApplicationBuilder.

The `AddService(this IServiceCollection services, MySettingsClass settings)` also gets some settings that should be used.

I need those exact settings in the `UseService(this IApplicationBuilder app)` method but don't know how to access them here.

How do I bring those settings from ConfigureServices to Configure without passing it twice (e.g. `UseService(this IApplicationBuilder app, MySettingsClass settings)`).

Comment: Register `MySettingsClass` itself with DI and then request it in your `IApplicationBuilder` extension via the `IApplicationBuilder` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IOption`, example

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddService(this IServiceCollection services, [NotNull]Action<ServiceConfigModel> configuration)
{
    services.Configure(configuration);

    return services;
}
```

Then get the value of object `ServiceConfigModel` by inject `IOptions< ServiceConfigModel> configuration` (call `configuration.value` to get the value).